# NetLogo BehaviorSpace Crashing NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

This is less of a coding question than a question about the program not working as a whole, apologies if it is mis-placed.

[Edit: I'm running NetLogo on MacOS Big Sur v11.1)

After a hiatus of about 5 months of not using NetLogo, I recently updated to 6.2.0 after my earlier version (6.0.3) had problems running BehaviorSpace.

When I opened BehaviorSpace in the old version, NetLogo ceased to be functional: all buttons were frozen, except for occasionally "Run" for an experiment. Running an experiment, along with the excel output, would occur, but I couldn't click any of the buttons (like Update View). Before running an experiment, I could not expand the BehaviorSpace window or  edit any of the parameters that I had set up months ago. I'm also unable to create a new experiment.

This continues to happen with the new version of NetLogo (6.2.0)- everything freezes, including the NetLogo Menu, but I can run an experiment if I don't mind not altering anything.

[EDIT: I've opened a model from the included Model Library, and BehaviorSpace similarly freezes the entire program, so it's not just my file... which is a relief]

Has anyone seen this, too? Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to any other computers? Or a friend who doesn't mind installing some software? It would be useful information to open the file in some other computer (with v6.2.0) and see if there's a problem - isolate to the file or the computer

Comment: Thanks @JenB, those are good suggestions. I'm going to try to remote in to my school machine to see if I can open the file- appreciate your input! .

Comment: You may need to report the problem at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/